# How to Optimise Each Multithreading Technique? (Cooperative/Preemptive/Simultaneous)

Tags: optimization, concurrency, parallel-computing, simulation, multi-tasking

I am currently in the process of writing an IB Extended Essay on the efficacy of multithreading on increasing the performance of applications. So far, I have been able to deduce that there are three main multithreading techniques:

- Cooperative/Coarse-Grained/Block  Multithreading
- Preemptive/Fine grained/Interleaved Multithreading
- Simultaneous Multithreading

My question:  Under what circumstance is each method of multithreading considered to be the optimal one to use? I assume one or the other will perform better with a higher number of cores, repetitive instructions, low/high remote access latencies or low/high remote cache miss rates, etc.

This means that if I were to create a simple program in Java with two versions, one using multithreading and the other not, I want to be able to see the largest possible processing time difference between the two versions.

P.S Can they all even be implemented at the user level (i.e. coded into commercial software)?

Comment: A few resources: https://www.realworldtech.com/alpha-ev8-smt/  https://www.realworldtech.com/niagara2/ https://www.realworldtech.com/super-heavyweights/8/  and of course the famous https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Architecture-Quantitative-Approach-Kaufmann/dp/0128119055/ref=dp_ob_title_bk

Comment: It's helpful to show us what research you've done and what you've found so far.  If you haven't done any yet, I suggest doing that now and then coming back to update your question afterwards.